# I'm not able to go to 'if' condition

Tags: python

I tried the below code for a normal sample problem, but my program doesn't go into the 'if' condition?

```
bus_list=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
seat_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
bus_num= input("enter the bus number\n")
print(bus_num)
if bus_num in bus_list:
    print("available seats are \n" +seat_list)
    seat_take=input("enter you seat number\n")
    if seat_take in seat_list:
        print("seat available")
    else:
        print("sorry! seat taken")
else:
    print("bus doesn't exists")
```

Comment: "Why can't I find a string in a list full of integers?"

Comment: Python 2 or Python 3? In Python 3, you'll have a *string* value `bus_num`, not an integer.

Answer (score 2):

`input()` returns a string, you need to convert it to an integer first:

```
bus_num= input("enter the bus number\n")
```

becomes:

```
bus_num = int(input("enter the bus number\n"))
```

Comment: Not only the right code, but an explanation too.

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
bus_num = input("enter the bus number\n")
```

to

```
bus_num = int(input("enter the bus number\n"))
```

Otherwise you'll have this problem

```
>>> '5' in [1,2,3,4,5]
False

>>> 5 in [1,2,3,4,5]
True
```

Comment: bus_num = int(input("enter the bus number\n")) didnt worked. it showed me error that is Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\RAHUL\Desktop\python progrms\sample.py", line 6, in <module>
    print("available seats are \n" +seat_list)
TypeError: Can't convert 'list' object to str implicitly

Comment: That's a totally different error, completely unrelated to the issue in your question. Replace `+` with `,` and get yourself a Python book.